# format() in the output string

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I have a code:

```
print "{0} is my {1}".format("Bruce","name")
```

and I get the expected output:

```
Bruce is my name
```

Now, I modified the code to:

```
print "{1} is my {2}".format("Bruce","name")
```

and I got a `IndexError: tuple index out of range`.

So, am I always supposed to start numbering from `0`?
I am new to Python programming so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, in Python indexing into sequences starts at `0`.

Since your `str.format()` parameters only have two values there is no value to interpolate with index `2`, only `0` and `1`, so an `IndexError` is thrown.

In general, for any sequence of elements, the indices run from `0` through to `len(sequence) - 1`. For a sequence with 2 elements, the last index then is `1`, for length 42, the last element is found at index `41`, etc.

Also see [*Why Python uses 0-based indexing*](http://python-history.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/why-python-uses-0-based-indexing.html), a blogpost where Guido van Rossum, the creator of Python, explains why Python indexing starts at 0, not 1.

Note that you don't *have* to number the slots (unless you are stuck with Python 2.6 or 3.0). You can just omit the numbers and Python will auto-number them for you:

```
print "{} is my {}".format("Bruce", "name")
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, let's say we have a two-word list as `lst = ["hello", "world"]` and we execute the following commands:

```
print lst[0] # calling on the 0ith element
>> 'hello' # we get the first word from the list
print lst[1] # calling on the 1st element
>> 'world' # we get the second word from the list
print lst[2] # calling on the 2nd element
>>IndexError: list index out of range # we get an error because it does not exist
```

**However....** please note that:

```
print(len(lst))
>> 2
```

Meaining that a list *item* starts with 0, but when you *count* the number of items (in this case "words") it starts with 1.

Comment: Answer is a bit confusing - maybe clarify!